# Hidden Button if no select option from document.getElementById .setAttribute href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have option select using javascript, and i want to hide the button if no select

This my code :

```js
function updateinput(e) {
 
var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
var name = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-name");
document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
var link = document.getElementById('data-url');
link.href = url;
link.textContent = name;
}
```

```css
#data-url{
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com' data-name="Google">30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com' data-name="Yahoo">60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```

How to hide the button if no select options? (i mean i want to hide the button "Anchor" if no select)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess by default 30 day is selected? When will be the situation that no option is selected?

Comment: It would probably make more sense if your `select` started out with nothing selected, rather than `30 Day` ("Google") selected, is that an option?

Comment: thanks sir for reply, yes sir, if default or no select, the button "Anchor" is hide, how to sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the first option of the select list will be selected. So to achieve what you want we can add a new default option in the list...

```js
function updateinput(e) {
 
var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
var name = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-name");
var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
if(name != 'default')
{
  document.getElementById('url-anchor').style.display = 'block';
  var link = document.getElementById('data-url');
  link.href = url;
  link.textContent = name;
}
else
{
  document.getElementById('url-anchor').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

```css
#data-url{
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
<option data1='' data2='' data3='' data4='' data5='' data-url='' data-name="default">Select period</option>
<option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com' data-name="Google">30 Day</option>
<option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com' data-name="Yahoo">60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<div id="url-anchor" style="display:none"><a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a><div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a blank value `option` in the `select` dropdown and add a condition in your code,

```
if(!name){
  link.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```js
function updateinput(e) {

  var selectedOption = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex];
  var url = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-url');
  var name = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-name");
  document.getElementById('data1').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data1');
  document.getElementById('data2').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data2');
  document.getElementById('data3').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data3');
  document.getElementById('data4').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data4');
  document.getElementById('data5').value = selectedOption.getAttribute('data5');
  document.getElementById('data-url').setAttribute('href', url);
  var link = document.getElementById('data-url');

  link.href = url;
  link.textContent = name;
  if (!name) {
    link.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#data-url {
  font: bold 11px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<select onChange="updateinput(event)">
  <option value=''>--select--</option>
  <option data1='1.000.000' data2='0,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='1.000.000' data-url='http://google.com' data-name="Google">30 Day</option>
  <option data1='1.500.000' data2='500.000,-' data3='0,-' data4='0,-' data5='2.000.000' data-url='http://yahoo.com' data-name="Yahoo">60 Day</option>
</select>

<input id="data1" name="data1" readonly type="text">
<input id="data2" name="data2" readonly type="text">
<input id="data3" name="data3" readonly type="text">
<input id="data4" name="data4" readonly type="text">
<input id="data5" name="data5" readonly type="text">
<a id="data-url" name="data-url">Anchor</a>
```